# Can I respond to a Survey Monkey survey by API?

Tags: surveymonkey

I have a page with another layout to my survey monkey survey.

Can I send this responses by API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, see the API docs at:

https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#survey-responses

Example:

```
POST /v3/collectors/<collector_id>/responses
{
  "custom_variables": {
    "custvar_1": "one",
    "custvar_2": "two"
  },
  "pages": [{
    "id": "12345678",
    "questions": [
    {
        "answers": [{
            "choice_id": "12345678"
        }],
        "id": "12345678"
    }]
  }]
}
```

See the documentation for more details on how to use the API.